# jQuery function not working with data that has been loaded with Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

When user clicks a link, it runs `$.post` to retrieve some data and display it. One of the links pulls a table of sessions with a button next to every session. Here is the code for one of the buttons:

```
<button class="view_session btn btn-info" id="3f87d50493698d06b9b48abe36cd8fc8">Details</button>
```

And here is my jQuery function:

```
$('.view_session').click(function(){
    $('#blanket').show();
    $('#load').show();
    $.post("admin/session.php", { id: $(this).attr('id') }, function(data){
        $('#sort').html(data);
        $('#first').hide();
        $('#load').hide();
        $('#blanket').hide();
    }); 
});
```

But nothing happens. I put in a `Console.log` to test and nothing triggered. Is there something I have to do because the button is being created after the page loads initially?

Comment: where did you put the `console.log` test?

Comment: *Is there something I have to do because the button is being created after the page loads initially?* -- That depends on where the `click` binding is being created, but probably, yes. You should bind to the click event after the button is added to the page, or use event delegation.

Comment: The button have to exist to you bind the event. You can use the jquery ready function. Or use the live instead click.

Comment: what is your server-side java or php ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are dynamically adding the button, `.click` will not bind to it unless it is already there.  You either need to bind *after* the button is added to the DOM or use delegation, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.view_session', function () {
```

(a more specific selector than `document` would be nice).

Other than that, the third argument as a function to `$.post` only occurs on success.  You can use the deferred interface methods to check for failure and completion as well:

```
$.post(...).then(success).fail(failure).done(complete);
```

Comment: In regards to your comments on the now deleted other answer which used `live()`. As far as I can tell OP did not specify the version of JQuery? For all I know OP is using 1.6 in which `live()` is perfeclty fine. Though using `Delegate()` instead would be more prudent. `live()` would have done the exact same as using `on()` with delegation. However, it is correct that in version 1.7 or later `live()` is depracated and should be replaced by 'on()`

Comment: @FrançoisWahl when it's not specified I usually make the assumption of latest jQuery version.  Probably not the best assumption, but it is true that 1.6 and lower do not have `.on`.  `.live` will *not* do the exact same thing as `.on`, because with the latter you can delegate to a more specific selector.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something I have to do because the button is being created
>   after the page loads initially?

Yes.

The reason for this is that handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the binding occurs.

The solution is that you either have to re-bind the event manually to the element ones it has been added or bind the event using delegation.

For jQuery 1.7 or later use `on()` with delegation:

```
$("#YourclosestStaticElement").on("click", ".view_session", function () {
   //... same code as before
}
```

For jQuery 1.4.3 up-to/including 1.6 use `delegate()`:

```
$("#YourclosestStaticElement").delegate(".view_session", "click", function () {
   //... same code as before
}
```

For jQuery 1.3 up-to/including 1.4.3 `live()` would be the only way, aside from re-binding manually:

```
$(".view_session").live("click", function () {
   //... same code as before
}
```

In addition there is a whole lot of reasons why `live()` was depracated, among the fact that it always bubbles up to the document before triggering the event, meaning `stopPropogation()` can become an issue for example.

The whole list of reasons is also in the `live()` documentation.

To quote from the [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

> - $(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
> - $(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
> - $(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+